# LibVLC C# expose opengl texture for shaders

Tags: c#, opengl, libvlcsharp

Is there any way to get the opengl texture for a video when the frame is loaded to apply some sort of effect shader on the image (like obs or mpv does)? I want to apply a image filter (https://github.com/bloc97/Anime4K) on the source, but for that I need the base texture binding to edit it. For this I need something like the built in videoeffects in standard vlc, but I dont see any bindings for that in LibVLC. If someone could point me in the right direction on how to aquire the texture ***or*** override something like https://github.com/videolan/vlc/blob/e7e608e84e9e218886700a6c90e8788a01f46b4f/modules/video_filter/ripple.c from c# code that would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libvlc 4 will have an API for that : https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#gafae363ba4c4655780b0403e00159be56

It is not yet available in libvlcsharp (version 4) as we don't know if the API is in its final form, but contributions are welcome, this is definitely something we should add.

Answer (score 0):

While you will be able to use the new output callbacks APIs in libvlc 4, as cube45 pointed out, you can already set one of the video filters in libvlc 3.

To retrieve the list of available video filters, run

```
var videoFilters = LibVLC.VideoFilters;
```

You should print them on the console and save them somewhere. On the next run, you can add them to the LibVLC constructor, like so

```
--video-filter=<string>    Video filter module
          This adds post-processing filters to enhance the picture quality, for
          instance deinterlacing, or distort the video.
```

https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Do note that filter performance will be improved in LibVLC 4, the processing is currently done in the CPU (will be GPU).

There are also audio filters available.